# Passing a 2D array in a function in C program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Below program (a toy program to pass around arrays to a function) doesn't compile.
Please explain me, **why is the compiler unable to compile(either because of technical reason or because of standard reason?**)

I will also look at some book explaining pointers/multi dimensional arrays(as I am shaky on these), but any off-the-shelf pointers here should be useful.

```
void print2(int ** array,int n, int m);

main()
{
    int array[][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}};
    int array2[][2]={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8}};
    print2(array,2,4);
}

void print2(int ** array,int n,int m)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<m;j++)
       printf("%d ",array[i][j]);

       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This (as usual) is explained in the [c faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html). In a nutshell, **an array decays to a pointer only once** (after it decayed, the resulting pointer won't further decay).

> An array of arrays (i.e. a
>   two-dimensional array in C) **decays
>   into a pointer to an array, not a
>   pointer to a pointer**.

Easiest way to solve it:

```
int **array; /* and then malloc */
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943909/manipulate-multidimensional-array-in-a-function

Answer (score 5):

In C99, as a simple rule for functions that receive "variable length arrays" declare the bounds first:

```
void print2(int n, int m, int array[n][m]);
```

and then your function should just work as you'd expect.

Edit:
Generally you should have a look into the order in which the dimension are specified. (and me to :)

Comment: What if i don't want to pass the dimensions from the function?

Comment: @Dchris, could you please be more clear what you want to know? You don't want to give dimensions at all, or you want to pass in fixed dimensions?

Comment: I want to pass in fixed dimensions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943909/manipulate-multidimensional-array-in-a-function

Answer (score 0):

In your code the double pointer is not suitable to access a 2D array because it does not know its hop size i.e. number of columns. A 2D array is a contiguous allotted memory.

The following typecast and 2D array pointer would solve the problem.

```
# define COLUMN_SIZE 4
void print2(int ** array,int n,int m)
{
    // Create a pointer to a 2D array
    int (*ptr)[COLUMN_SIZE];
    ptr = int(*)[COLUMN_SIZE]array;

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
       printf("%d ", ptr[i][j]);
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```