# 2D array passing to a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I've been reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321670/passing-a-2d-array-in-a-function-in-c-program) but I'm not able to get the resulting code to solve the problem. 
How should I change this in order to make it work?

```
void print2(int ** array,int n, int m);

main()
{
    int array[][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}};
    int array2[][2]={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8}};
    print2(array,2,4);
}

void print2(int ** array,int n,int m)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<m;j++)
       printf("%d ",array[i][j]);

       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by **"I'm not able to get the resulting code to solve the problem"**?

Comment: Compiler is unable to compile the program.. Following error is presented: `warning: passing arg 1 of print2 from incompatible pointer type`
I don't understand the solution which is given in the previous question :s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing in a pointer to an array, but your function is expecting a pointer to a pointer. **In C, the array name decays to a value that is the pointer to the first array element**. In this case, the first array element is an array, so the function argument decays to a pointer to an array.

Here is one way you can fix this. Change the function to take a `void *` so that the dimension does not interfere with the argument. Then the dimension argument is used in the function body to create the proper pointer type for the 2D array.

```
void print2(void *p,int n,int m)
{
    int i,j;
    int (*array)[m] = p;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<m;j++)
          printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If you are willing to change the order of the arguments, then you can use the proper type for the array argument:

```
void print2(int n, int m, int array[n][m])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<m;j++)
          printf("%d ",array[i][j]);
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Since Jack asked about C89, here's a way to handle it. Since a 2D array is organized the same as a long 1D array in memory, you can just walk the passed in pointer as such. Again, we accept the input parameter as a `void *` to avoid dealing with the decayed type. Then, we treat the pointer as a long 1D array, but we walk it according to the proper dimensions:

```
void print2(void *p, int n, int m)
{
    int i,j;
    int *array = p;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<m;j++)
          printf("%d ",array[i*m+j]);
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this last `print2()` function valid in C89?

Comment: @Jack: Both my answers rely on variable length array. Neither are valid for C89.

Comment: @Jack: I added a C89 solution.

Comment: Thanks very much again. I +1 if I could. Also,Don't get me wrong with: "As I imagined." wasn't my intention to be "rough".

Answer (score 0):

In your question you are passing arguments as pointer to an array.
Do as given below :

```
void print2(int (*array)[4],int n,int m)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<m;j++)
       printf("%d ",array[i][j]);

       printf("\n");
    }
}
```