# C: passing a 2D array to a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

First of all: yes, I know this is a common topic and I've tried several proposed solutions. Nothing worked for me (at least nothing with "nice" code), I finally tried the way described here (2nd variant in jxh's solution):
[2D array passing to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822496/2d-array-passing-to-a-function)

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef double real32;

void Multiply_Matrix_Vector38(int n, int m, real32 A[n][m], real32 B[m], real32 Result[n]);

int main()
{
  real32 A[3][8];
  real32 B[8];
  real32 Result[3][3];
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    A[0][i] = i;
    A[1][i] = i+1;
    A[2][i] = i+2;
    B[i] = i;
    B[i] = i;
    B[i] = i;
  }

  Multiply_Matrix_Vector(3, 8, A[3][8], B[8], Result[3]);
  return 0;
}

void Multiply_Matrix_Vector(int n, int m, real32 A[n][m], real32 B[m], real32 Result[n])
{
  uint8 i, j;
  real32 sum;

  sum = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++  {
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      sum = sum + A[i][j] * B[j];
      printf("A %f\n", A[i][j]);
    }
    Result[i] = sum;
    sum = 0;
  }
}
```

I still get incompatible type errors - how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

As arrays decays to pointers when being passed to a function, what's really passed is `real32 (*)[8]` and `real32 *`.

You can modify the function appropriately:

```
void Multiply_Matrix_Vector38(int n, int m, real32 (*A)[m], real32 *B, real32 *Result);
```

---

You also calling the function with the wrong arguments. You're calling it with a single value in the arrays, and not the arrays themselves. And remembering that array indexes goes from zero to size minus one, you're also out of bounds.

Instead do just

```
Multiply_Matrix_Vector(3, 8, A, B, Result);
```

---

Oh, and do you really want `Result` to be an array of arrays too?

Answer (score 1):

Your are not passing the arrays when you do `Multiply_Matrix_Vector(3, 8, A[3][8], B[8], Result[3]);`

Rather, you are passing the element of A at (3,8), the 9th element of B.

Your call should be the following : `Multiply_Matrix_Vector(3, 8, A, B, Result[0]);`

The error should have helped you with that : your are passing doubles instead of arrays of doubles.

Result is n array of 3 arrays of size 3, thus `Result[0]`, `Result[1]`, and `Result[2]` have the correct types. `Result[3]` is out of bounds however.

Finally your function prototype should be `void Multiply_Matrix_Vector(...)` not `void Multiply_Matrix_Vector38(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You missed a couple of things, like the `)` in.

```
for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
```

Also you should have called

```
Multiply_Matrix_Vector(3, 8, A, B, Result[3])
```

Instead of.

```
Multiply_Matrix_Vector(3, 8, A[3][8], B[8], Result[3])
```

Because your arguments `A[3][8]` and `B[8]` are real32 variables (you are accesing to an element of the matrix and an element of the vector), instead of that you have to use `A` and `B`.

And finally, you have to declare.

```
void Multiply_Matrix_Vector(int n, int m, real32 A[n][m], real32 B[m], real32 Result[n]);
```

Above the main function to use it there.

**Note:** Result should be an array, because if multiply A (3x8) with B (8x1), the result should be an array with dimensions 3x1.