# Segmentation faul while accessing 2d array?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define     GRID_X              30
#define     GRID_Y              20

unsigned char board[GRID_Y][GRID_X];

void draw_board( unsigned char ** );
void print_board( unsigned char ** );

int main()
{
    draw_board( board );
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void draw_board( unsigned char **board )
{

    unsigned int  r_itr = 0,
                  c_itr = 0;

    if( NULL == board )
    {
        printf( "cannot create board..!!" );
        exit(0);
    }

    r_itr = 0;

    for( c_itr = 0; c_itr < GRID_X; ++c_itr )
    {
        board[ r_itr ][ c_itr ] = '+'; /* <- crashing here  */
        board[ r_itr + ( GRID_Y-1 ) ][ c_itr ] = '+';
    }

    c_itr = 0;

    for( r_itr = 0; r_itr < GRID_Y; ++r_itr )
    {
        board[r_itr][c_itr] = '+';
        board[ r_itr ][ c_itr + GRID_X-1 ] = '+';
    }

    print_board( board );
 }

void print_board( unsigned char **board )
{
    int r = 0,
        c = 0;

    for( r = 0; r < GRID_Y; ++r )
    {
        for( c = 0; c < GRID_X; ++c )
        {
            printf( "%c", board[r][c] );
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The above code is crashing at the point I mentioned via comment ( crashing here ).
I did all the possible boundary-checking ( based on my understanding ), I am still not able to detect the reason for crashing?
I used GNU GCC compiler and code blocks IDE.please help?

Comment: The data type of your function parameter is wrong. `board` is not a `unsigned char **`; its an array of arrays. They are NOT synonymous.

Comment: Why are you passing `board` to all your functions as argument, when it is a global variable?

Comment: i know its weird but its actually not a global i made it to express my doubt in a simple manner.

Comment: So many C beginners think an array will decay to a pointer when they pass it, but it decays only once, so a 2D array wouldn't decay to a pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
void draw_board( unsigned char board[][GRID_X] )
```

or

```
void draw_board( unsigned char (*board)[GRID_X] )
```

**Update**

Why does the function `draw_board`, as defined in the question, cause problems?

Let's say you have

```
char b[2][3] = {{0}, {0}};
```

The layout of memory for the array is:

```
<--- b[0]     --->|<--- b[1]     --->

a1    a2    a3    a4    a5    a6
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

where `a1` ... `a6` are addresses.

When you pass `b` to a function, it decays to a pointer and the value passed to the function is `a1`.

Let's say you have a function `foo` declared as:

```
void foo(char** b);
```

When you pass the `b` to foo, the value of `b` in `foo` is `a1`.

```
b[0] = *b = *a1
```

The data being held at address `a1` is now being treated as a `char*`. If the size of a pointer is 4 bytes,

```
b[0] = 0;
```

If you dereference `b[0]`, such as in an expression `b[0][0]`, you will get undefined behavior.

Comment: ok i see data type mismatch is there. but how it leads to crashing?

Comment: @user2070804 because its **wrong**. you're using the wrong pointer type and thus have an invalid alias, Therefore your program invokes *undefined behavior* when using that pointer. Thus the program is *ill-formed* and *may* crash.(and in this case, is highly likely to do just that). +1, btw, on the answer

Comment: ill-formed and may crash.ok i got you.still didnt explain why its crash. the statement "board[r_itr][c_itr]" will alwats read one byte right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for 2-d matrices, the expressions `unsigned char[][]` and `unsigned char **` are not compatible. The [C language FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html) and this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321670/passing-a-2d-array-in-a-function-in-c-program) will explain the differences.

When you compiled your code, you should have seen a warning like the following. This is from gcc:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'draw_board' from incompatible pointer type
```

If you want to fix the problem and keep `draw_board()` the same, you need to declare `board` as `unsigned char **` and allocate memory like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <conio.h>

#define     GRID_X              30
#define     GRID_Y              20

//unsigned char board[GRID_Y][GRID_X];
unsigned char **board;

void draw_board( unsigned char ** );
void print_board( unsigned char ** );

int main()
{
    board = (unsigned char **) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char *) * GRID_X);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < GRID_X; i++)
    {
        board[i] = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * GRID_Y);
    }

    draw_board( board );
    //getch();
    return 0;
}
```